# Can't initialize array with pre-defined variable int

Tags: c++

```
int shifts[c] = {0};
```

The c is defined. Error: shifts maybe not be initialized. Why? What am I doing wrong here? I think it has something to do with c, but I am not sure. If I can't use the current declaration, how do I get around it? I tried it with vectors first:

```
vector<bool> shifts(c, false)
```

But, it didn't work. Had bad_alloc error.

---

```
int max = 0, min = 10000;
for (int i = 0; i != 2*no_shifts; ++i) {
    int x;
    fin >> x;
    time.push_back(x);

    if (max < x)
        max = x;

    if (min > x)
        min = x;
}
c = max - min + 1;
```

Comment: `c` has to be a compile-time constant for the array declaration. Is it?

Comment: What's the value of `c` when you execute that line?

Comment: Yes. Umm, I don't know. 'c = max - min + 1' max and min are int. Is there something wrong with this?

Comment: @IshaanSingh How are `max` and `min` defined?  Can you show more code, at least enough to see exactly what `c` gets set to, ideally an entire but short program

Comment: You probably get `bad_alloc` because `c` is negative and is converted into an unsigned type, which makes it really big.

Comment: `c` is not a constant expression since it involves `max` and `min` which are non-`const`. Variable-length arrays are not part of C++ and your compiler may have restrictions on how they can be used. (In C99, variable-length arrays may not be initialized.)

Comment: @Brian But, max and min are non-negative (x is non-negative). And, under any rate min must be less than max, for a given input. Okay, so what can I do?

Comment: @IshaanSingh, if `no_shifts` is zero then the loop won't run at all.

Comment: @Brian But no_shifts will never be zero. This a problem on USACO training page, that I have been trying to solve (milk2).

Comment: @IshaanSingh If you can reproduce the issue, I suggest you use a debugger to examine the value of `c` just before the vector initialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based solely on `c = max - min + 1;` it seems that you are trying statically initialize an array without a compile time constant. Either use a dynamically allocated array or `std::vector` if you need something that can have it's size determined at runtime.

**Edit:** You may actually want to consider using `std::bitset` instead as an alternative container.

Comment: So, if I use vector<bool> shifts(c, false), will it work? How do you get the grey padding around the code (inline)?

Comment: `std::vector<bool> shifts(c, false);` should make a vector with c amount of bool all set to false with the default allocator. You use the ` key to inline code snippets.

Comment: Make sure you create the vector *after* calculating the value of `c` to use